# SMPP Server and Client applications C#

Tags: .net, smpp

I'm going to build a C# library that handles the SMPP protocol (client/server).

So, can I get any help for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your attitudes you may either try to build SMPP protocol functionality or use some ready available component, especially one of those available for .NET world.

1) Building SMPP client/server on your own is certainly time consuming. Most probably not justified economically mostly because SMPP is complicated, supporting multitude of scenarios (encodings, concatenated messages, synchronous/asynchronous operation modes etc. etc.), and it's definition is not complete (e.g. Appendix B is not always followed precisely resulting in confusion on both client and server side) and you have to build up your expertise.

2) There are few components, some of them native .NET assemblies, of various quality and references to choose from, e.g.:

[SMSC Client .NET / SMSC server .NET](http://www.tops.com.pl/en/) duo

[InetLab SMPP component](http://www.inetlab.com/)

Jamaa SMPP Client (client functionality only)

And other, mostly not .NET native solutions but also usable in C# (like COM components) easy to find.

Summing up - following my long personal experience with various messaging protocols, it is most reasonable to off load the pain with different SMPP configurations/implementations on third party. Which usually means prompt and competent support is a key.